# JMeter Selenium Sampler crashes when trying to click on button using PhantomJS config

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, phantomjs

I've created a JMeter Project and am using WebDriver Sampler (Selenium) to capture response times when interacting with a certain webpage feature.

I've tested the project using both Firefox and Chrome Driver configs.  When I try to use PhantomJS it freezes when I click on a specific button.

I've inspected the HTML code and found that a modal sits on top of all the web elements I need to interact with.

I've asserted against the button, confirming it's present, visible, and enabled.

Any ideas around how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of the popup it needs to be handled differently. For example, [JavaScript Confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) (Yes/No) dialog which looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="somebutton" value="clickme" onclick="return confirm('Hello, JMeter')"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Can be worked around like:

```
var By = org.openqa.selenium.By
var ExpectedConditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
var wait=new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://some.url')
WDS.browser.findElement(By.id('somebutton')).click()
WDS.browser.executeScript('window.confirm = function(){return true;}');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more tips and tricks on Selenium and JMeter integration

Comment: Thanks.  This didn't resolve the problem but helped confirm the cause is not related to the click command but the onclick function.  I used executeScript to run the onclick function.  It works when using Chrome Driver but fails when using PhantomJS Driver.  Now the problem is how do I debug within Jmeter to identify where the script is failing.